# Запуск проекта на Windows - Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: javascript

```
"build:js": "browserify ./src/app.js -t [ babelify --optional es7.classProperties ] --outfile public/all.js",
"build": "watch 'npm run build:js' ./src"
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как запустить, проект под виндовс, получаю ошибку, на линуксе наблюдение за изменениями в файла проходит нормально:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я бы удивился, если бы кто-то смог помочь. Проверяйте версию ноды, пути.. Я давным давно по таким же причинам с windows и свалил.

Comment: И я вспомнил основную причину по которой ушел! Когда нажимал `npm install`, то устанавливались не все зависимости. Приходилось копировать их в блокнот и по одной устанавливать. Возможно и у Вас тоже самое?